# Subdomain redirecting to www

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I setup two virtual hosts for a subdomain in my apache config. One for SSL and one for non-SSL redirecting to SSL. This is it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.tld

    Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.domain.tld/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/subdomain"
    ServerName subdomain.domain.de

    <Directory "/var/www/subdomain">
            AllowOverride All
            allow from all
            Options +Indexes
    </Directory>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.tld/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.tld/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Apparently I also use Let’s Encrypt.

DNS is setup as follows:

```
subdomain.domain.tld IN A <IP address of server>
```

Problem is, that any request to subdomain.domain.tld in my browser will ultimately redirect to https://www.subdomain.domain.tld.

The setup does not even cover any requests to www.

Why is it redirecting my request to www? This is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

It was not related to the apache config, instead it was the worpress instance hosted, that did a 301 redirect.

Sorry.